# Errordocument not redirecting to custom 404 page

Tags: php, .htaccess

So I have a website and I want it to redirect to a custom 404 page I made when it gets a 404 status, so this is inside my `.htaccess` file:

```sh
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 https://domainname.com/404.html
```

Which also contains code to remove the extensions to be able to go to a page like this `domain/file` without having to specify the trailing extension and `Options -Indexes` to disable directory browsing. Now when I go on a page that does not exist I get this page:

(PS: I'm using brave browser thus the presence of the wayback machine prompt)

[image: Page]
and this status:

```sh
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

But it does not redirect to my 404 page as specified in my `.htaccess file`.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding

```sh
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

and replaced `Options -Indexes` by `Options All -indexes`.
to the top of `.htaccess` file.